# Haskell. Programación de árboles. Error al modificar el valor

Tags: haskell

Estoy empezando con Haskell y aun patino mucho.

Estoy intentando modificar el valor del nodo de un árbol y me da error en los tipos.

Les dejo el código aquí debajo.

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias

```
module Arbol where

data Valor a = Null | Valor a
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)
data Arbol a = Vacio | Nodo (Valor a) (Arbol a) (Arbol a)
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

-- Función num2bin: recibe un Int y devuelve una lista con los
-- dígitos de su representación en binario --

num2bin :: Int -> [Bool]

num2bin 0 = [False]

num2bin n = num2binAux n

  where num2binAux :: Int -> [Bool]

        num2binAux 0 = []

        num2binAux n = (num2binAux (div n 2) ) ++ [ ( mod n 2 ) == 1]

-----------

esVacio :: Eq a => Arbol a -> Bool

esVacio ar = if ar == Vacio

                then True

                else False

----------------------------------
-- Función newArbol: devuelve un Arbol vacío --

newArbol :: Eq a => Arbol a
newArbol = Vacio

-------------------------------------------

-- Función poner: recibe un Arbol, una posición y un elemento y cambia el valor del Arbol de dicha posición 

poner :: Eq a => Arbol a -> Int ->  a -> Arbol a
poner sa n elemento = anadir sa lista elemento
    where lista = num2bin n



anadir :: Eq a => Arbol a -> [Bool] -> a -> Arbol a

anadir Vacio lista elemento = anadir ( Nodo Null newArbol newArbol ) lista elemento

anadir (Nodo _ izq der) [] elemento = Nodo elemento izq der

anadir (Nodo _ izq der) ( True : xs) elemento = Nodo Null izq (anadir der xs elemento)

anadir (Nodo _ izq der) (False : xs) elemento = Nodo Null (anadir izq xs elemento) der
```

---

Mensaje de error:

```
Prelude> :l stack.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Arbol            ( stack.hs, interpreted )

stack.hs:36:44: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Valor a
    * In the first argument of `Nodo', namely `elemento'
      In the expression: Nodo elemento izq der
      In an equation for `anadir':
          anadir (Nodo _ izq der) [] elemento = Nodo elemento izq der
    * Relevant bindings include
        elemento :: a (bound at stack.hs:36:28)
        der :: Arbol a (bound at stack.hs:36:20)
        izq :: Arbol a (bound at stack.hs:36:16)
        anadir :: Arbol a -> [Bool] -> a -> Arbol a
          (bound at stack.hs:35:1)
   |
36 | anadir (Nodo _ izq der) [] elemento = Nodo elemento izq der
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error intenta darte toda la información que necesitas, aunque a veces puede resultar difícil de interpretar.

Te avisa de estar creando un *tipo infinito*, que hay que entender como que hay una definición recursiva, como ocurre en tu caso.

En la línea:

```
anadir (Nodo _ izq der) [] elemento = Nodo elemento izq der
```

En la signatura de la función, `elemento` es de tipo `a`, pero lo que espera `Nodo` es que le pases un tipo `Valor a`. El compilador interpreta que `elemento` tiene que ser a la vez `a` y `Valor a`, algo que solo sería posible si fuera un tipo infinito del estilo `Valor (Valor (Valor .... (Valor a)))`.

La solución pasa por usar el constructor para pasar `elemento` a `Valor a`:

```
anadir :: Eq a => Arbol a -> [Bool] -> a -> Arbol a

anadir (Nodo _ izq der) [] elemento = Nodo (Valor elemento) izq der
```